# File root is out of space after fresh installation

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu yesterday after removing windows but its giving me error saying no space on File Root,

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M  2.4M  784M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  468G  445G     0 100% /  <---- Why is this consuming so much memory 
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop1      223M  223M     0 100% /snap/code/82
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop4      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop3      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop5      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11993
/dev/loop6       51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop7      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop8       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop9      130M  130M     0 100% /snap/teams/6
/dev/loop10      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop11      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop12      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/loop13     296M  296M     0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/loop14     427M  427M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/256
tmpfs           787M   20K  787M   1% /run/user/125
/dev/loop15      43M   43M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14066
tmpfs           787M  168K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop16      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1242
/dev/loop17      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop18     248M  248M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
```

Comment: Looks like you already asked this question earlier today, and received appropriate advice on your next step.

Comment: actually the above answer didn't help , i am worried because this doesn't allow me to use any of my apps anymore ,

Comment: Discussion about that question's advice should take place in that question. Please do not open a new question with the same information; we will simply tell you the same thing that @OrganicMarble did. "*It didn't help*" is not enough information to offer useful advice.

Comment: According to you this is a new installation, so please edit your question and describe all of the things you've done since the system was installed. 400GB+ is a lot of data. Are you sure you have no idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$ du -m -h / | grep G` That will show everything at least 1.0GB in size. But use uppercase G. Locate whatever is obscenely large and delete it.

Comment: giving me these in response `du: cannot read directory 'proc/4155/ns': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory 'proc/4178/task/4178/fd': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory 'proc/4178/task/4178/fdinfo': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory 'proc/4178/task/4178/ns': Permission denied
`

Comment: `3.5G /var
1.9G /home/atif/.local/share/Trash/files/backup_files
432G /home/atif/.local/share/Trash/files
432G /home/atif/.local/share/Trash
432G /home/atif/.local/share
432G /home/atif/.local`
@Brain it is showing me these files that 're way larger

Comment: thanks that command at the end did help , i owe you rest of my laptop age